# Is there a way to use awk to REMOVE lines based on threshold value?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a bunch of identifiers in the first column and scores for individual samples (for those identifiers) in the next columns, like this;

```
ID       1         2          3
21       20        70         80
13       44        50         10
```

I know the `awk` syntax to count how many instances there when every value in a row is less than 20 `(($2 < 20) && ($3 < 20) && ($4 < 20))`, but I don't know how to filter them out.

If I do `(($2 > 20) && ($3 > 20) && ($4 > 20))` and print those and save them, it is not the same, because you will have instances in the first example where one value is less than 20 and the row is still kept because not ALL values are less than 20 (e.g.   10     40     45) . With the `>` version, all values must be greater than 20, so this row would have been deleted.

Can you please help me? Maybe I need `sed`?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please state your objective clearly and simply? You want to remove all lines where any field is less than 20 maybe? Or where all fields are more than 20? Or what?

Comment: If you're struggling to do something with awk you do NOT need sed! [edit] your question to show the expected output given that sample input. Also you'll find it much easier to state your requirements if you think in temrs of what you want to print, not what you don't want to print. So if you, say, don't want to print lines where $1 is less than 20, state your requirement as "I want to print lines where $1 is greater than or equal to 20" -  same behavior but no negatives and so much clearer and simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most probably doing something wrong.The statement *"you will have instances in the first example where one value is less than 20 and the row is still kept because not ALL values are less than 20 (e.g. 10 40 45)"*  is not valid. Using && you ask for a logical AND and chained AND will result to output if all conditions AND returns true; meaning that the row is not kept:

```
$ echo "10        40         45" |awk '(($1<20) && ($2<20) && ($3<20))'
#Output : no output
```

If you want to keep above row then you need OR:

```
$ echo "10        40         45" |awk '(($1<20) || ($2<20) || ($3<20))'
#Output:
10        40         45
```

Similarly :

```
$ echo "10        40         45" |awk '(($1>20) && ($2>20) && ($3>20))'
# Output: No Output
$ echo "10        40         45" |awk '(($1>20) || ($2>20) || ($3>20))'
#Output:
10        40         45
```

Comment: I do want to keep that row but I want to remove any rows where ALL values are less than 20, hence the &&. I can print all these rows with the command I used: awk '{(($2 < 20) && ($3 < 20) && ($4 < 20))}'

but I want to remove them!

My point was if I try to print with >20, the output will not have rows where all values are 20, but I will also lose rows where one value is under 20.  Actually, I think the OR operator might work: as long as one value is greater than 20, it will be kept!

Comment: @DanS Men , i suggest to follwow the advises in comments. Forget about AND and OR and rephrase your question. Tell us what you have as input ( a couple of rows) and tell us what you expect as output. Might be simplier than all this AND/OR/NOT confusion.

Comment: @DanS By the way you know that your code home some curly brackets that normally should not be there, right? Compare your code with my examples

Comment: Thanks, it's all good! The OR operator did the job. And the curly braces are not necessary in this example but seems like they are necessary when I need to print only one of the columns (e.g. '{ if (($2 < 20) && ($3 < 20) && ($4 < 20)) print $1}'). It all works, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if one of the value doesn't satisfy your condition iterating to `NF` and print the whole line according to this  :

```
awk '{ 
        if (NR != 1){
            remove = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
                if ($i < 20) {
                    remove = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (remove == 0){
                print $0
            }
        }
    }' test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear what you're asking without the provided desired output.  Also, your input file seems to have a header increasing confusion.

This is the alternatives you can use, comment indicates what records will be printed.  You can extend to additional columns.

```
   awk -v t=20 '$2<t && $3<t' file         # all strictly less
   awk -v t=20 '!($2<t && $3<t)' file      # any greater or equal 
   awk -v t=20 '$2<t || $3<t' file         # any strictly less 
   awk -v t=20 '!($2<t || $3<t)' file      # all greater or equal
```

perhaps will help you to understand, these basic equalities

```
  !(p && q) == !p || !q    # for logical p,q
  !(p || q) == !p && !q
     !(x<y) == x>=y        # for numerical x,y
```